# Text is not showing up on labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a GUI program using python 3.6.4 and tkinter for a programming assignment that essentially randomly generates values, combines them with existing string, and displays it all on a bunch of labels.

My issue is that the text simply isn't showing up on the label. The label formats itself based on the text, but there is no text visible.

I've already searched everywhere for someone else with a similar problem however I haven't been of any luck.

Be warned that I'm very new to all of this, and my code is likely a huge mess. I apologize in advance for a potentially brain tumor inducing code.

```py
def new_win():

    import tkinter as tk

    newwin = Tk()

    def runBreif():

        global year
        global market
        global location
        global minCompetitiveness

        yearD = str(['Year:', year])
        marketD = ['Market:', market]
        locationD = ['Location:', location]
        minCompetitivenessD = str(['Minimum score:', minCompetitiveness])

        def title():
            varTitle = StringVar()
            TileL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varTitle, relief = RAISED, font = 'roman 25 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey', fg = 'red')
            #Setting message
            varTitle.set('Your task:')
            #Packing welcome message
            TileL.pack()
            print('Your task:')

        def yearDisplay():
            global year
            varY = StringVar()
            yearL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varY, relief = RAISED, font = 'arial 15 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey')
            #Setting message
            varY.set(yearD)
            #Packing welcome message
            yearL.pack()
            print(yearD)

        def marketDisplay():
            global market
            varM = StringVar()
            marketL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varM, relief = RAISED, font = 'arial 15 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey')
            #Setting message
            varM.set(marketD)
            #Packing welcome message
            marketL.pack()
            print(marketD)

        def locationDisplay():
            global location
            varL = StringVar()
            locationL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varL, relief = RAISED, font = 'arial 15 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey')
            #Setting message
            varL.set(locationD)
            #Packing welcome message
            locationL.pack()
            print(locationD)

        def scoreDisplay():
            global minCompetitiveness
            varS = StringVar()
            scoreL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varS, relief = RAISED, font = 'arial 15 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey')
            #Setting message
            varS.set(minCompetitivenessD)
            #Packing welcome message
            scoreL.pack()
            print(minCompetitivenessD)

        def BreifDisc():
            global breif
            varB = StringVar()
            breifL = Label( newwin, textvariable = varB, relief = RAISED, font = 'arial 10 bold', width = 80, height = 3, bg = 'light grey')
            #Setting message
            varB.set(breif())
            #Packing welcome message
            breifL.pack()
            #print(breif())
```

This is the part of my code where I format the labels. Ignore the print()s, those are just for me to check whether the code is properly generating the variables (which it is).

I would post images of my output and the issue in question, but apparently I'm not reputable enough to do so.

Here is a dropbox link to my full program if you wish to see it
https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Saves/autoinspiration_V_0.06_ALPHA.py?role=personal

Comment: If you are only setting text then you can set text when creating a label ```Label(newwin, text = "...")```

Comment: On a side note, the code is a bit of mess, I am not sure why you define all of the functions in another function. If you feel the need to use global variables then I would suggest looking at OOP (Object-oriented programming)

Comment: All of your `StringVar`s are being referred to only via local variables, and are therefore being garbage collected as soon as the containing function returns.  Either make them globals, or skip them completely and set the Label's `text=` option instead.

Comment: @jasonharper That defiantly solved my issue, text is now displaying. Thanks!